# Question on $ \dfrac{2^{3n}+3^k+1}{2^{n+1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let t = $ \dfrac{2^{3n}+3^k+1}{2^{n+1}},\ n \in (1, 2, 3, \dots),\ k \in (2, 5, 8, \dots),\ $ if $t$ is an odd integer, prove $3$ divides $t$.

Comment: So.. what have you tried?

Comment: @QC_QAOA I tried at least $n=1, k \in  (5, 11, 17, \dots),\ $ no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For each integer $k$, note that $(3^k+1)\pmod 8$ is either $2$ [if $k$ is even] or $4$ [if $k$ is odd].

If $(3^k+1) \pmod 8$ is $2$, then for $t$ to be an integer then, note that $n$ cannot be a positive integer. So $t$ is never a positive integer if $(3^k+1)\pmod 8$ is $2$.

If $(3^k+1)\pmod 8$ is $4$ then for $t$ to be an integer, $n$ must be $1$. And so $3n$ must be $3$. But then what do you know about $2^3+1$? What divides $2^3+1$?